# exe4j fails unable creating temp directory (potentially causing Windows error 7)

Tags: exe4j

We use exe4j 4.4.4 to build an exe that runs our Java program. One of our customers is complaining that sometimes they are getting "Windows error 7" when running our exe. This only happens intermittently and only on a couple of machines out of hundreds.

We enabled exe4j debugging and noticed that in cases when we get the error exe4j log file contains several entries like the one below and then ends. However, on successful exe launch the log file goes beyond these entries and eventually launches our Java program.

These are the last several log messages in exe4j log file when we get the error:



*GetTempPath returned 14 (last error 183)

make dir returned -1

tempPath is C:\WINNT\TEMP\

tempFile is C:\WINNT\TEMP\e4j38.tmp

Temp dir: C:\WINNT\TEMP\e4j38.tmp_dir

Could not create dir (183)

GetTempPath returned 14 (last error 183)

make dir returned -1

tempPath is C:\WINNT\TEMP\

tempFile is C:\WINNT\TEMP\e4j39.tmp

Temp dir: C:\WINNT\TEMP\e4j39.tmp_dir

Could not create dir (183)

GetTempPath returned 14 (last error 183)

make dir returned -1

tempPath is C:\WINNT\TEMP\

tempFile is C:\WINNT\TEMP\e4j3A.tmp

Temp dir: C:\WINNT\TEMP\e4j3A.tmp_dir

Could not create dir (183)*

Comment: If I'm not mistaken Exe4j creates another executable in a temporary directory. Sounds like it's doing that in a write protected directory (c:\winnt is usually not writeable for regular users). This was one of the reasons I chose Winrun4J over Exe4J

Comment: But the problem happens intermittently on the same machine! And the user does see a bunch of exe4jxx.tmp_dir folders in C:\WINNT\TEMP from successful launches. And what does "GetTempPath returned 14" means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in exe4j which caused it to cycle through its temp folders after a bunch application restarts. Exe4j reduced the chance for temp folder collisions in 4.4.5 version by adding a timestamp to the names of their temp folders.